# Как получить данные из Firebase Database?

Tags: kotlin, firebase, firebase-database, kotlinx-coroutines

Есть функция:

```kotlin
fun DatabaseReference.takeAll(): Any {

    this.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                val counter = snapshot.childrenCount
                if (counter > 1) {
                    val list: MutableList<String>? = null
                    for (i in snapshot.children) {
                        list?.add(i.key.toString())
                    }
                } else if (counter == 1L) {
                    val data = snapshot.value.toString()
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Take All Function: snapshot is not exist")
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, error.message)
        }

    })

}
```

Её задача — достать данные из БД по определенному пути и вернуть мне их.

У меня несколько вопросов:

1. Что писать как возвращаемое значение, т. к. оно может быть и списком и просто строкой.
2. Как в конце функции вернуть значение *только* когда данные полностью загрузятся, чтобы после вызова я их записал и пошел дальше работать.

Пробовал вернуть в `for` или в `else if`, но ругается на то, что функция `onDataChange` должна возвращать `Unit`. При попытке вернуть не `Unit` ругается на `override`, что предсказуемо.

Запускается функция из main-потока, но можно реализовать её как корутину. Вызывать я планирую её примерно вот так:

```kotlin
val data = путь.takeAll()
```

И дальше какие то действия с ней.

Comment: Функция `takeAll` не может вам вернуть данные, так как она лишь занимается тем, что регистрирует некоторый EventListener, который *отложенно* в будущем вызовет (а может и никогда не вызовет) метод `onDataChange`. Поэтому "здесь и сейчас" `takeAll` вам ничего не вернет.

Comment: @Vadik, хорошо, а как лучше эту задачу реализовать?

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужно использовать [единоразовое](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_once_using_get) чтение из базы. А регистрация [слушателя](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_with_persistent_listeners) позволяет читать данные непрерывно.

Comment: @Vadik, единоразовое чтение у FB тоже асинхронное, так что автор попадет в тот же капкан "вернуть синхронно результат асинхронного вызова."

Comment: @ДмитрийКолесник нужно больше контекста, откуда вы вызываете эту функцию? Из какого потока? Если из main-потока, то его блокировка приведет к "зависанию" вашего приложения, поэтому *синхронно* вернуть данные из базы категорически плохо. Что используете для многопоточности в вашем приложении, м. б. rxjava или корутины? [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1317702/edit) вопрос, добавьте подробностей.

Comment: @ДмитрийКолесник также постарайтесь сфокусировать ваш вопрос только на одной конкретной проблеме. Тогда с большей вероятностью вам смогут помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По [документации Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_once_using_get), чтобы единоразово вытащить данные из базы, нужно выполнить следующий код:

```kotlin
database.child("users").child(userId).get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { data ->
        println("Пользователь: ${data.value}")
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        println("Не удалось получить пользователя из базы")
        exception.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Для удобной интеграции [Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) с корутинами есть расширение [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services). Экстеншен `await()` упростит работу с отложенными `Task`. Тот же самый код будет выглядеть так:

```kotlin
try {
    val data = database.child("users").child(userId).get().await()
    println("Пользователь: ${data.value}")
} catch (exception: Exception) {
    println("Не удалось получить пользователя из базы")
    exception.printStackTrace()
}
```

Экстеншен `await()` является suspend-функцией, поэтому может быть вызван только из другой suspend-функции либо из корутины.

Comment: Здравствуйте, не очень понимаю в чем проблема. Пытаюсь написать такую функцию: 

` fun DatabaseReference.t(){

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        try{

            this@t.child("").get().await()

        }catch (e: Exception){



        }

    }


}
 ` 


Но ругается на await() говорит что такой функции нет нет.

Comment: Подключите [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) в ваш проект.